# Filtering outliers before using group by

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with price column (p) and I have some undesired values like (0, 1.50, 92.80, 0.80). Before I calculate the mean of the price by product code, I would like to remove these outliers

```
                Code    Year    Month  Day   Q      P
0               100     2017       1    4   2.0  42.90
1               100     2017       1    9   2.0  42.90
2               100     2017       1   18   1.0  45.05
3               100     2017       1   19   2.0  45.05
4               100     2017       1   20   1.0  45.05
5               100     2017       1   24  10.0  46.40
6               100     2017       1   26   1.0  46.40
7               100     2017       1   28   2.0  92.80
8               100     2017       2    1   0.0   0.00
9               100     2017       2    7   2.0   1.50
10              100     2017       2    8   5.0   0.80
11              100     2017       2    9   1.0  45.05
12              100     2017       2   11   1.0   1.50
13              100     2017       3    8   1.0  49.90
14              100     2017       3   17   6.0  45.05
15              100     2017       3   24   1.0  45.05
16              100     2017       3   30   2.0   1.50
```

How would be a good way to filter the outliers for each product (group by code) ?

I tried this:

```
stds = 1.0  # Number of standard deviation that defines 'outlier'.
z = df[['Code','P']].groupby('Code').transform(
    lambda group: (group - group.mean()).div(group.std()))
outliers = z.abs() > stds
df[outliers.any(axis=1)]
```

And then :

```
print(df[['Code', 'Year', 'Month','P']].groupby(['Code', 'Year', 'Month']).mean())
```

But the outlier filter doesn`t work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC You can use a groupby on `Code`, do your `z` score calculation on `P`, and filter if the `z` score is greater than your threshold:

```
stds = 1.0 
filtered_ df = df[~df.groupby('Code')['P'].transform(lambda x: abs((x-x.mean()) / x.std()) > stds)]

    Code  Year  Month  Day     Q      P
0    100  2017      1    4   2.0  42.90
1    100  2017      1    9   2.0  42.90
2    100  2017      1   18   1.0  45.05
3    100  2017      1   19   2.0  45.05
4    100  2017      1   20   1.0  45.05
5    100  2017      1   24  10.0  46.40
6    100  2017      1   26   1.0  46.40
11   100  2017      2    9   1.0  45.05
13   100  2017      3    8   1.0  49.90
14   100  2017      3   17   6.0  45.05
15   100  2017      3   24   1.0  45.05

filtered_df[['Code', 'Year', 'Month','P']].groupby(['Code', 'Year', 'Month']).mean()
                     P
Code Year Month           
100  2017 1      44.821429
          2      45.050000
          3      46.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. Just take the Boolean opposite of your `outliers['P']` series via `~` and filter your dataframe via `loc`:

```
res = df.loc[~outliers['P']]\
        .groupby(['Code', 'Year', 'Month'], as_index=False)['P'].mean()

print(res)

   Code  Year  Month          P
0   100  2017      1  44.821429
1   100  2017      2  45.050000
2   100  2017      3  46.666667
```